# Why is typescript triggering an error in my HOC that uses rest props when I try to pass another prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-functions

I've written a wrapper to connect components to a store by injecting a store prop. The wrapper code is working correctly and passing tests.

```
import React, { ComponentType } from 'react';
import store from './index';
import { RootStore } from './RootStore';

interface InjectedStoreProps {
  store: RootStore;
}

const withStore = (WrappedComponent: ComponentType<InjectedStoreProps>) => {
  const output = ({...props}) => <WrappedComponent store={store} {...props} />;
  return output;
}

export default withStore;
```

However, in one of my tests I have

```
const ComponentToWrap = withStore(
  ({store, otherProp}) => (
    <div>
      <span>
        {store}
      </span>
      <span>
        {otherProp}
      </span>
    </div>
  )
);
```

which is causing the typescript error `Type 'PropsWithChildren<InjectedStoreProps>' has no property 'otherProp' and no string index signature.`

I am new to typescript, so could definitely be misunderstanding something. I've tried things from many google searches but none of them have helped.

React v16.8.6
Typescript v3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is that you're trying to deconstruct (https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/destructuring.html) an object that has no property `otherProp`. You can fix that by adding it:

```
interface InjectedStoreProps {
  store: RootStore;
  otherProp: any;
}
```